# Force driver to kill running/hanged worker

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark job that sometimes hang when running an Oracle query through jdbc. I don't know the cause, but I'd like to find a setting that could tell the driver to kill this worker so it can be rerun (when I do it manually it works).
I've found 2 settings that could do, but i'm not sure :

- spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout
- spark.excludeOnFailure.timeout

The second one seems to trigger only on failure, but the worker is still in a running state (no failure, just doing nothing), is the first one ok ?
Is there another parameter that could solve my problem ?

It occurs rarely (once or 2 a month) impossible to reproduce.
I'm suspecting an Oracle overload peak or a network, but no way to prove it.

Thanks à lot

Comment: Or your query is trying to update a row that another session has locked and you are waiting for the lock to be released.

Comment: Unlikely, no lock seen on database, and the Oracle session is no longer present on the database while executor is still seen running in yarn application.

Comment: Work with your DBA to determine the real state of your database session and go from there. It may be as simply as query tuning.

Comment: I'm dba, so I already checked that ;)